# Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, modernizr

I'm a masochist, so I decided to change the way in which I load require.js in my project. All I did was go from this (using Modernizr.load)...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function requireJsConfig () {
        requirejs.config({
            'baseUrl': '{{ STATIC_URL }}js',
            'paths': {
                'jquery': 'libraries/jquery',
                'backbone': 'libraries/backbone',
                'underscore': 'libraries/underscore',
                'jquery.cookie': 'libraries/jquery-cookie',
                'tinymce': 'tinymce/tinymce.min',
                'react' : 'libraries/react',
                'history': 'history'
            },
            waitSeconds: 30,
            shim: {
                'jquery' : 'jquery',
                'underscore' : {
                    exports: '_'
                },
                'backbone': {
                    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                    exports: 'Backbone'
                },
                'jquery.cookie': {
                    deps: ['jquery'],
                    exports: '$.cookie'
                },
                'tinymce': {
                    deps: ['jquery'],
                    exports: 'tinymce'
                }
            }
        });

        define('static_url', [], "{{ STATIC_URL }}");
        window.static_url = "{{ STATIC_URL }}";
        define('PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY', [], "{{ PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY }}");

        require(["teacher"]);
    };

    Modernizr.load({
        load: '{{ STATIC_URL }}js/require.js',
        complete: function() {
            requireJsConfig();
        }
    });

</script>
```

...to this (not using Modernizr.load)...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/require.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function requireJsConfig () {
        requirejs.config({
            'baseUrl': '{{ STATIC_URL }}js',
            'paths': {
                'jquery': 'libraries/jquery',
                'backbone': 'libraries/backbone',
                'underscore': 'libraries/underscore',
                'jquery.cookie': 'libraries/jquery-cookie',
                'tinymce': 'tinymce/tinymce.min',
                'react' : 'libraries/react',
                'history': 'history'
            },
            waitSeconds: 30,
            shim: {
                'jquery' : 'jquery',
                'underscore' : {
                    exports: '_'
                },
                'backbone': {
                    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                    exports: 'Backbone'
                },
                'jquery.cookie': {
                    deps: ['jquery'],
                    exports: '$.cookie'
                },
                'tinymce': {
                    deps: ['jquery'],
                    exports: 'tinymce'
                }
            }
        });

        define('static_url', [], "{{ STATIC_URL }}");
        window.static_url = "{{ STATIC_URL }}";
        define('PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY', [], "{{ PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY }}");

        require(["teacher"]);
    };

    requireJsConfig();

</script>
```

...and now I'm getting this:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function
>   (){return r}

FWIW, this is where the error is happening (in require.js):

```
function intakeDefines() {
    var args;

    //Any defined modules in the global queue, intake them now.
    takeGlobalQueue();

    //Make sure any remaining defQueue items get properly processed.
    while (defQueue.length) {
        args = defQueue.shift();
        if (args[0] === null) {
            return onError(makeError('mismatch', 'Mismatched anonymous define() module: ' + args[args.length - 1]));
        } else {
          //args are id, deps, factory. Should be normalized by the
          //define() function.
          callGetModule(args);
        }
    }
}
```

And by the way, I've already verified that none of [these](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) apply.

Why did this seemingly innocuous change cause a nuclear bomb to explode in my project? (Yes, an *actual* nuclear bomb detonated...as if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror, and were suddenly silenced...)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can explain it better than Patrick did...

You do not need a `shim` for `underscore` because it detects whether it is running with an AMD loader, and if so, then it calls `define`. **Don't use `shim` for modules that call `define`.**

You should also remove the `shim` for jQuery. Unless you are using an ancient version, it also detects that it is running with an AMD loader and calls `define`. Moreover the `shim` `jquery: "jquery"` is meaningless. (The closest meaningful `shim` I could think of would be `jquery: ["jquery"]` which would mean "`jquery` depends on `jquery`".)

As to why it would have worked before... when you use `shim` with modules that call `define` you enter undefined territory: sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

I don't know whether the other modules need shims or not because I don't use them regularly. If I were you, I'd check whether they call `define`.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense logically, but after removing jquery, underscore, and backbone from the shim (all of which support AMD), I get different errors when I start my server, such as `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` trying to create Backbone models or `$.ajaxSetup is not a function`. And the errors are coming from different scripts in the require chain each time I start the server. So it appears that jquery, underscore, and backbone are not being loaded now, even though the first line of my first required script is `require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', ...])`.

Answer (score 0):

You said "none of these apply", however unless you hand modified underscore, it [certainly does](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1558-L1560).

Comment: But I'm not manually loading underscore in an HTML `<script>` tag. My `requireJsConfig()` function calls `require(["teacher"])`, and the first line of my teacher.js file is: `require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', ...])`.